# Show product alert link /stock alert, when a product is quantity zero, but still in stock

Tags: magento2, stock, product-alert, stock-alert

I am trying to add the "notify me when product is back in stock" link to a product that is still "in stock" but with a quantity of zero.

Is this possible by modifying the module product-alert?

At this moment the notification link is only visible when a product is labeled as "out of stock".

Comment: A quantity of zero means the product is out of stock. No?

Comment: When backorders are allowed, which is true in this case, then products need to remain in stock to be able to still backorder them.
If set to out of stock, then it is not possible to backorder products.